# Tracking a chat window event, how do I get these two scripts to work together?

Tags: javascript, events, chat, tracking

I am trying to track an event using the following code, but to me it seems like they are not immediately compatible as what I wanted to do was not validating.

```
Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {};
Tawk_API.onChatStarted = function(){
    //place your code here
};
```

How would I add this event tracking code to the above?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
wc_event_ypbib
(
"User", //Category - Required
"Chat", //Action - Required
"New Chat", //Label - Optional
);
//]]>
</script>
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, just place your code where it says "place your code here." Like so:

```
Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {};
Tawk_API.onChatStarted = function(){
  //place your code here
  wc_event_ypbib
  (
    "User", //Category - Required
    "Chat", //Action - Required
    "New Chat" //Label - Optional
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that. I am working on a site without FTP access so I need to be absolutely sure the code is valid or the site will break. I'm using a code validator and it says the above gives an error. Unexpected ')'.

Comment: Ah--there's an extra comma after "New Chat", so JavaScript is expecting another argument. Remove that and it should be fine. (I've updated my answer.)